# Search for full word instead of part inside of it

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I'm trying to find exact word in text user is sending, but obviously, when I'm trying to use `message.content.includes()`, it's also looking for parts of the word in text which I don't need! Any way to search by full words only?

Few examples: `**TexT**`, `HeLlO`, etc.

Comment: You can use `regex` regular expressions to search only for exact matches.

Comment: You should add some examples of what the user inputted text is and what the words are to make your question a bit clearer.

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros Basically it should be something like bad words filter

Comment: why don't you just do something like `String#includes(" text ")` (spaces at the start and end)

Answer (score 0):

Put your content in to an array, splitting words if it's a piece of text. `Array.includes` will match whole words.

So either use `[content].includes(word)` if content is a single word, or `content.split(' ').includes(word)` if content is multiple words.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can use a regex like this, assuming `wordToFind` holds the word you are searching for:

```js
// Create regex from word with \b at each end which
// means "word boundary", and the 'i' option means
// case-insensitive
const wordSearch = new RegExp(`\b${wordToFind}\b`, 'i');

// Use the regular expression to test the content:
const hasWord = wordSearch.test(message.content);

// will be true if whole word is found
```